# Lombok @Builder Cannot resolve method 'builder'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-14

IntelliJ is throwing an error compilation "Lombok Cannot resolve method 'builder'" on the builder method using @Builder annotation.

Comment: I just upgraded to 2023.2 and now I have the exact problem :/

Answer (score 3):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-262693). Note that Lombok in 2020.3.3 is also affected by the [serious performance regression](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-264579).

[Downgrading](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html) to 2020.3.2 is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the issue was, that I used the .builder() method on an abstract class

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).